# "getimagesize(): SSL operation failed with code 1" on local Xampp only

Tags: php, xampp, getimagesize

getimagesize() fails in Xampp (local PC), although it works fine in the live environment.

Based on the error message, the issue seems related to certificate configuration. I have created self-signed certificates based on this article: https://shellcreeper.com/how-to-create-valid-ssl-in-localhost-for-xampp/

This removed the SSL warning from Apache's error log, but the issue with getimage() is still the same.

If I pass the image's URL with `http` instead of `https`, the call works.

```php
<?php
$file = "http://webtest.test/content/uploads/img.jpg";  // Will work
$file = "https://webtest.test/content/uploads/img.jpg"; // Will not work

// ...

$img_info = getimagesize($file);
if(!$img_info) {
  throw new Exception(__("The file type is not valid image (1)"));
}
?>
```

Error received:

```
PHP Warning:  getimagesize(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:\nerror:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in \\xampp\\htdocs\\index.php on line 3, referer: https://webtest.test/
PHP Warning:  getimagesize(): Failed to enable crypto in \\xampp\\htdocs\\index.php on line 3, referer: https://webtest.test/
PHP Warning:  getimagesize(https://webtest.test/content/uploads/photos/2019/08/2f203cfc1e.jpg): failed to open stream: operation failed in \\xampp\\htdocs\\index.php on line 3, referer: https://webtest.test/
```

Xampp/PHP version 7.3.6.
Loaded modules:

```
core mod_win32 mpm_winnt http_core mod_so mod_access_compat mod_actions mod_alias mod_allowmethods mod_asis mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_dav_lock mod_dir mod_env mod_headers mod_include mod_info mod_isapi mod_log_config mod_cache_disk mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_proxy mod_proxy_ajp mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_socache_shmcb mod_ssl mod_status mod_php7
```

Where could the problem be coming from, and how to fix it ?

Comment: Update your CA bundle. Most likely you are missing one or it is out of date.

Comment: Supposedly the manipulation explained in the linked article has the CA bundle generated and handled by Windows. I simply double-clicked the crt file and followed the steps. In php.ini I read "`If openssl.cafile is not specified or if the CA file is not found, the directory pointed to by openssl.capath is searched for a suitable certificate. This value must be a correctly hashed certificate directory.
 Most users should not specify a value for this directive as PHP will
attempt to use the OS-managed cert stores in its absence.`. Maybe the problem is coming from there then :-/

Answer (score 6):

If you're trying to get image size from your own servers images dir, you can use `base_path` instead of `url().'pathtoyourimage'`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the CA bundle to Apache SSL fix this.

```
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/My_CA_Bundle.ca-bundle
```

Answer (score 1):

Only one way correct!

For apache2 + php: set to CAcerteficate in file php.ini -> [openssl] -> openssl.cafile= /etc/ssl/chain/YOURDOMAIN.COM/yourCAchain.crt

Answer (score 1):

When you get this error:

```
getimagesize(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

You can solve it like so:

```
list($w,$h) = getimagesize(ROOTINDEX."admin/upload/post-images/".$value['post_image']);
```

So you can write this:

```
list($w,$h) = (ROOTINDEX."admin/upload/post-images/".$value['post_image']);
```

And your code will be executed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thanks for your answer! Legibility for your answer can be improved by using code blocks which you can create by surrounding code with one or three ticks (`\``).